# KVM - Get segment register value

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, x86, virtualization, kvm

I'm trying to get segment register value from KVM.

```c
struct vcpu_vmx *vmx = to_vmx(vcpu);        
vmx_get_segment(vcpu, &vmx->rmode.segs[VCPU_SREG_FS], VCPU_SREG_FS);
        
printk("%p\n",&vmx->rmode.segs[VCPU_SREG_FS].base);
```

But i couldn't get the register value from KVM. I would like to achieve something like that (from asm perspective).

```c
__asm__("mov %%fs:0, %0":"=r"(val));
```

Comment: Are you sure that's what you want to do? Isn't `mov %%fs:0, %0` actually dereferencing the address `%fs:0`? Of course the result of that instruction will be completely different. Also, AFAICT `segs[VCPU_SREG_FS].base` is not getting you the value of the guest FS, if that's what you want; it's getting the base address of the segment descriptor associated with FS. You should clarify your question.

Comment: So it seems like you want to get the base address for the segment, not the actual value in the segment register (which is the 16-bit selector).  That is what's normally stored at address `%fs:0` in the Linux userspace ABI. Is this 32- or 64-bit code?  For 32-bit code you have to look in the descriptor table, for 64-bit in the hidden FSBASE register.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli when i do `mov %%fs:0, %0` in userspace i can take current executed thread id. so it's same for `pthread_self()` for a process. actually i just want to get current executed thread id from kvm.

Comment: @NateEldredge thanks for your response i think that what i want. now i just i use `vmcs_readl(GUEST_FS_BASE)` and it works like a charm